# Hyperledger fabric: An org can only see some details of the transaction

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I am working on a dapp project only using Hyperledger Fabric. The situation is, a bank transfers money from account A to account B. This transaction is recorded in the blockchain. The thing is there will be a role similar to a supervisor. I just want the supervisor to know there was such a transaction and know some detail while some other details are hidden to the supervisor. Can HL Fabric achieve this? Or how can I achieve this?

Comment: You should show what you have tried to solve this problem, as it currently outside the scope of what SO provides.

Comment: You can emit EVENTS ( with some data you want to show )  and the supervisor can subscribe to those events and knows the transaction took place between A and B.

Comment: @jaswanth Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hyperledger Fabric 'private data collections’ when participants need to transact on the same blockchain, but keep data private to a subset of transactors (and potentially regulators/auditors). Private data is shared peer-to-peer, with hashes stored on the blockchain as evidence so that all peers can validate transactions.

With private data collections, you can keep the entire state private, or make part of the state public, and part of the state private.

See the Fabric [private data documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/private-data/private-data.html) and a [tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/private_data_tutorial.html).